# MongoDB filter documents based on items in other collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Say, I have 2 collections. Users and Orders as below:
**Users**

```
{
 id: '01',
 name: 'john'
},
{
 id: '02',
 name: 'donald'
}
```

**Orders**

```
{
  id: '01',
  userId: '01'
},
{
  id: '02',
  userId: '02'
},
{
  id: '03',
  userId: '01'
}
```

I want to match all the Users that have more than 1 Order. I'm using localField, foreignField later in the pipeline. Example code being used:

```
db.Users.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
   activated: true
  }
},
{
 $sort: {
   Date: -1
 }
}
])
```

I want to filter some documents of **Users** collection based on the $lookup data. E.g `$lookup: {from: 'Orders', localField: 'id', foreignField: 'userId', as: 'orders'}`. how do I exclude documents from the aggregation that have fewer than 2 orders?

Comment: Please use lookup function for getting data

Comment: I want to filter some documents of "Users" collection based on the $lookup data.E.g $lookup: {from: 'Orders', localField: 'id', foreignField: 'userId', as: 'orders'}. how do I exclude documents from the aggregation that have fewer than 2 orders?

Comment: Please share collection and what you want data at json editor online ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `$match` after `$lookup` stage and apply your filtering based on [$size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/):

```
db.Users.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {from: 'Orders', localField: 'id', foreignField: 'userId', as: 'orders'}
    },
    {
        $match: { $expr: { $lt: [ { $size: "$orders" }, 2 ] } }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/IPVQnPjUWfO)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How would I further narrow down the filtering based on contents in $orders? Say, I want to show the Users who has less than 2 orders and both of them are shipped? imagine documents in Orders have a "is_shipped: true/false field

Comment: @ShakilAhmed you can add  `{ $allElementsTrue:  "$orders.is_shipped" } ` as another filtering condition https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/